# Why some types of ranked matches become unavailable?

Tags: starcraft-2

Upon HotS release I played mostly 1x1 ranked games... at some point 1x1 got 'unavailable' for me. I resolved that by hitting 'back' button to escape matchmaking screen and coming back.

But in 1-2 weeks later the same happened and i can't escape this limitation anymore: whatever i did I was not able to start any 1x1 match.

Ok, I played some 2x2 games... few weeks later I was forced to play 3x3 or 4x4... or, i thought I understood the rules: you should play EACH match type...

But now, I have played 1x1, 2x2, 3x3.. and available are 2x2 and 4x4...

**Why only certain types of games are available?**

**What is the rule here?**

Comment: The missing game types have been confirmed as a bug by Blizzard on reddit. I guess it should be fixed soon. Though, for me, this only happened temporarily as you did - never permanently. Maybe try logging into a different server and back?

Comment: @tenfour I can confirm you tenfour. Its a bug. It has nothing to do with rules or anything. Its a simple but. You can resolve it by logging in and out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like stated by tenfour, this is a know bug. 
Follow this link for an official blue post on solutions:
http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/8796679671#2

Quote:

- 1) Reset your network.
- 2) Flush the DNS cache.
- 3) Delete the Variables.txt file from
  C:\Users\\Documents\StarCraft II
- 4) Delete the Battle.net cache.

As for myself, I simply log out and log-in again.